# In iOS web app, on pageshow only elements which have "position:fixed" are visible

Tags: javascript, css, ios, next.js, safari

I have a iOS app, which is basically a web-page packed in a iOS app. The web-app is written in NextJS.

I have a page, let's call it page A. On page A there is a button that the user can tap to take him to the sign-in page. After the user signs in, they are redirected back to page A.

Now, earlier I was facing the issue that on redirecting back to page A, an API call that was supposed to be called on page load; the logic for which was inside `useEffect` of that page container, was not getting called. Safari was somehow caching the whole page as it is, due to which the signed-in state of the user was not getting showcased.

I solved this by added a `"pageshow"` event listener to `window`, so that everytime the page loads, the API call is made.

This worked well in Safari browser. But in the iOS app, I am now facing an issue where when user lands back to page A after signing in, the API call is made, but on the page only those elements which have `"position:fixed"` in their CSS are visible. Rest of the elements are in the DOM, but they are not visible. When I changed their position to `"fixed"` they became visible. Also as soon as I scroll the page, everything becomes normal.

Why is this happening? And how can this be fixed?

I used the dev-tools to inspect the web-page, and the elements are there in the DOM, but they are not visible. They become visible if I add `style="position: fixed"` or as soon as the page is scrolled.

Comment: `This worked well in Safari browser.`  Does it work well in Safari if you resize the browser very small, or use dev tools to emulate an iPhone?

Comment: `"pageshow" event listener to window,`  If your using React, your likely doing that bit wrong..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.